# How can I modify bit in position in Go?

Tags: go

I tried to modify bit at a certain position, but ran into a problem.
For example I have `1000000001`, how can I modify it to `0000000001`?

Comment: `v = v & ^0b1000000000` or `v = v & 0b0111111111`

Comment: What underlying type are you using? You posted 10 bits here. I imagine there are more being truncated off.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a bitmask to only keep the bits you are interested in.

In this case if you only want the last bit, you apply the bitmask **`0b0000000001`**

https://go.dev/play/p/RNQEcON7sw1

```golang
    // 'x' is your value
    x := 0b1000000001
    // Make the bitmask
    mask := 0b0000000001
    // Apply the bitmask with bitwise AND
    output := x&mask
    fmt.Println("This value == 1: ", output)
```

### Explaination

`&` is a [bitwise](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/go/go_bitwise_operators.htm) operator for "AND". Which means it goes through both values bit by bit and sets the resulting bit to `1` if and only if both input  bits are `1`. I included a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) for the AND operator below.

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| Input Bit | Mask Bit | Input & Mask |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
|         0 |        0 |            0 |
|         0 |        1 |            0 |
|         1 |        0 |            0 |
|         1 |        1 |            1 |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

Because my mask function only has a `1` in the last position, only the last position of the original input is kept. All preceding bits will always be `0`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Construct a mask that has a one in every place you want to manipulate
2. Use bitwise OR to set bits.
3. Use bitwise AND with the inverse mask to clear bits.
4. Use XOR to toggle a bits

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    k := 3                      // manipulate the 3rd bit ...
    mask := uint8(1) << (k - 1) // ... using 0b00000100 as a mask

    var n uint8 = 0b10101010
    fmt.Printf("0b%08b\n", n) // 0b10101010

    // set kth bit
    n |= mask
    fmt.Printf("0b%08b\n", n) // 0b10101110

    // clear kth bit
    n &^= mask                // &^ is Go's AND NOT operator
    fmt.Printf("0b%08b\n", n) // 0b10101010

    // toggle kth bit
    n ^= mask
    fmt.Printf("0b%08b\n", n) // 0b10101110
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func test() {
    i := 1 << 9 //1000000000

    i = i | (1 << 8) //1000000000 | 0100000000 == 1100000000
    i = i | (1 << 7) //1100000000 | 0010000000 == 1110000000
    i = i | (1 << 0) //1110000000 | 0000000001 == 1110000001

    fmt.Printf("BEFORE: %010b\n", i) // 1110000001

    i = i & ((1 << 9) - 1) // 1110000001 & ((1000000000) - 1) == 1110000001 & (0111111111) == 0110000001

    fmt.Printf("AFTER: %010b\n", i) // 0110000001
}
```